# Check if equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Check if $(x,y)\rho(a,b)\Leftrightarrow sgn(y-\pi x)=sgn(b-\pi a)$ is equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R^2}$, find the set of equivalence classes and $C_{(1,\pi)}$. Give geometric representation.

$1)$ $\rho$ is reflexive:
$(\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2})(x,y)\rho (x,y)\Leftrightarrow sgn(y-\pi x)=sgn(y-\pi x)$

$2)$ $\rho$ is symmetric: $(\forall (x,y),(a,b)\in \mathbb{R^2})(x,y)\rho (a,b) \Rightarrow (a,b)\rho (x,y)$

$(x,y)\rho (a,b) \Leftrightarrow sgn(y-\pi x)=sgn(b-\pi a)$

$(a,b) \rho (x,y)\Leftrightarrow sgn(b-\pi a)=sgn(y-\pi x)$

$3)$ $\rho$ is transitive:
$(\forall (x,y),(a,b),(u,v)\in \mathbb{R^2})(x,y)\rho (a,b) \land (a,b)\rho(u,v)\Rightarrow (x,y)\rho (u,v)$

$(x,y)\rho (a,b)\land (a,b)\rho(u,v)\Leftrightarrow sgn(y-\pi x)=sgn(b-\pi a) \land sgn(b-\pi a)=sgn(v-\pi u)\Rightarrow sgn(y-\pi x)=sgn(v-\pi u)\Rightarrow (x,y)\rho(u,v)$

From $1),2)$ and $3)$, $\rho$ is equivalence relation.

Equivalence class $C_{(1,\pi)}$ is $C_{(1,\pi)}=\{(x,y): y-\pi x=0\}$

How to find complete set of equivalence classes and represent it geometrically?

Comment: $C_{(1,\pi)}$ is the graph of the line with slope $\pi$ that goes through the origin. This line divides the plane into two half planes. Your equivalence relation says two points are equivalent if they lie in the same half plane.

Comment: @John Douma What would be the definition of a complete set of equivalence classes?

Comment: You have three equivalence classes: the line, the upper half plane and the lower half plane. This assumes $sgn$ takes on three values: $+$, $-$ and $0$.